# Sql Server - How to display words when Null?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having difficulty with this.

In SQL Server 2008 - I need to display the words "No Web Page" when their webpage is Null.

Here is the basic code I have so far. Not sure how to do this.

```
SELECT  VendorID,
    VendName,
    VendWebPage

FROM    Vendors;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT VendorID, ISNULL(VendName, 'No web page'),VendWebPage
FROM Vendors;
```

or this

```
SELECT VendorID, CASE 
                   WHEN VendWebPath IS NULL THEN 'No web page'
                   ELSE VendName 
                 END AS VendName, VendWebPage
FROM Vendors;
```

Depending on if you need to check VendName for null or VendWebPage for null.

Comment: Thank you! Our SQL teacher doesn't go over all material in class, and we don't have a textbook. Very helpful.

Comment: Checking Webpage for Null. We haven't covered If/Else statements yet, so I'm sure it's the first one.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT VendorID, 
       VendName, 
       coalesce(VendWebPage, 'No Web Page') as VendWebPage 
FROM Vendors
```